# VersionNotFoundException on changing the DataRow in BackgroundWorkerProgressChanged event

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview, windows, krypton-toolkit

This `row["FileProgress"] = e.ProgressPercentage;` code below is giving error of `VersionNotFoundException`. Please help because its creating havoc to the application, also I am facing Exception: [DataTable internal index is corrupted: '5'](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/adodotnetdataproviders/thread/18544cd3-1083-45fe-b9e7-bb34482b68dd) many times randomly.

**BackgroundWorker ProgressChanged code**

```
private void bwTransferQueue_ProgressChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    DataRow row = e.UserState as DataRow;
    if (row != null)
    {
        row["FileProgress"] = e.ProgressPercentage;     <--- VersionNotFoundException
    }
}
```

**BackgroundWorker DoWork code**

```
private void bwTransferQueue_DoWork(object sender, System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    DataRow row = e.Argument as DataRow;
    try
    {
        if (row != null)
        {
             // some code
             bwTransferQueue.ReportProgress(0, row);
        }
    }
    catch (WebException webex)
    {
        row["Status"] = QueueType.Failed;
        row["StatusDescription"] = webex.Status;
        e.Result = row;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        row["Status"] = QueueType.Failed;
        row["StatusDescription"] = ex.Message;
        e.Result = row;
    }
}
```

**Code to Start Background Worker**

```
private void startWorker()
{
    try
    {
         if (StartQueue && dtTransferQueue.Rows.Count > 0 && !bwTransferQueue.IsBusy)
         {
              DataRow[] rows = dtTransferQueue.Select(string.Format("Status = '{0}'", QueueType.Pending.ToString()));
              if (rows.Length > 0)
              {
                  tsmiProgressBar.Visible = true;
                  bwTransferQueue.RunWorkerAsync(rows[0]);
              }
         }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
          CommonLogic.HandleError(ex);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are modifying the `DataRow` on more than one thread.

The `DoWork` event of `BackgroundWorker` is raised on a background thread. When you call `ReportProgress`, the `ProgressChanged` event is raised on the GUI thread. The reason for this is so that you can easily update UI elements from the ProgressChanged event handler.

This may be why you are corrupting the the `DataTable` index.

As for the `VersionNotFoundException`, I can imagine that it's related to the multithreaded access/corruption in some way, but don't know for sure. However, I'd definately start by looking at how your threads are interacting with the `DataRow`.

Comment: @Harsh.Baid - That would get rid of the symptoms you're seeing, but will not correct the underlying issue, and you may simply start seeing weird problems, not necessarily exceptions. If you're going to carry on using a design which means the list is updated by multiple threads, you'll probably need to use some kind of synchronisation. I'd perhaps try locking on `dtTransferQueue` whenever I need to update a `DataRow` before making any larger changes to see if that makes a difference. However, threading as you know is a complicated topic and I can only offer limited advice based on your example.